# change values while reading a file / shell scripting loops ,

Tags: html, linux, bash, loops, shell

I have a log file that looks like this,

```
<tr><td>AAA-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>AAA-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>BBB-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>BBB-application-04 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>CCC-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr><td>CCC-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr><td>CCC-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
```

I am looping through this log file and generating a HTML report as a table. "AAA" , "BBB" , "CCC" and "DDD" are the application groups.
Here is the loop that I used there,

```
while read line; do
for item in $line; do 
     echo $item
done
done < filename.log
```

But when the table is created in the report the application groups cannot be identified seperately.
I mean they all prints the same. I want to seperate the application groups as it can be visually identified seperately in the report.
im going to use CSS or bootsrap styles, so its is better if I can change the class of  while rendering to the HTML.

So the end result should be like,

```
<tr class="red"><td>AAA-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr class="red"><td>AAA-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr class="green"><td>BBB-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr class="green"><td>BBB-application-04 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
```

so this means "AAA" applications will be red
"BBB" application will be green
"CCC" applicattion will be yellow

When creating the log file I cannot add HTML elements seperately to the application groups ,  because I use a one script to take all of those values to the log file.

I tried this so much for a long time and still couldnt figure out how to do this.

Any suggestion on doing this ??  is this approch is possible or impossible to do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << ==CSS==
<style>
        tr.red{
                background: red;
                color: white;
        }
        tr.yellow {
                background: yellow;
        }
        tr.green{
                background: green;
                color: white;
        }
</style>
==CSS==

awk -F"[-<>]" '
        BEGIN{
          classes["AAA"] = "red"
          classes["BBB"] = "green"
          classes["CCC"] = "yellow"
          print "<table border=1>"
          print "<thead><tr><th>Group</th><th>Application</th><th>Reason</th></tr></thead>"
          print "<tbody>"
        }
        {
          print "<tr class=\""classes[$3]"\">"
          print " <td>"$3"</td>"
          print " <td>"$4"-"$5"</td>"
          print " <td>"$7"</td>"
          print "</tr>"
        }
        END{
          print "</tbody>"
          print "</table>"
}' logfile
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant approach, did some changes and could apply to my case. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

In pure Bash (>= Bash 4) :

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -A colors=(
    [AAA]="red"
    [BBB]="green"
    [CCC]="yellow"
)

regex="^<tr><td>(...)-.*</td></tr>$"

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        entry=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        [[ -v colors[$entry] ]] && line=${line/<tr>/<tr class=\"${colors[$entry]}\">}
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < filename.log
```

Here, we match a regexp with the input string. If there is a match, and we know how to change the color, we substitute the first `<tr>` with a new string containing the color.

For example, with the following input :

```html
<tr><td>AAA-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>AAA-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>BBB-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>BBB-application-04 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr> 
<tr><td>CCC-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr><td>CCC-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr><td>CCC-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr><td>DDD-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr><td>DDD-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>  
<tr><td>DDD-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
```

You would get :

```html
<tr class="red"><td>AAA-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr class="red"><td>AAA-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr class="green"><td>BBB-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr class="green"><td>BBB-application-04 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr><td>DDD-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr><td>DDD-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
<tr><td>DDD-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the XML-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) and "[direct element constructors](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-element-constructor)":

```
$ xidel -s filename.log -e '
  x:replace-nodes(
    tr,
    function($x){
      $x/<tr class="{map{"AAA":"red","BBB":"green","CCC":"yellow"}(substring(td,1,3))}">{node()}</tr>
    }
  )
' --output-node-format=html
```

With "[computed constructors](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-computedConstructors)":

```
$ xidel -s filename.log -e '
  x:replace-nodes(
    tr,
    function($x){
      $x/element tr {
        attribute class {
          {"AAA":"red","BBB":"green","CCC":"yellow"}(substring(td,1,3))
        },
        node()
      }
    }
  )
' --output-node-format=html
```

Output in both cases:

```
<tr class="red"><td>AAA-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </br></td></tr>
<tr class="red"><td>AAA-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </br></td></tr>
<tr class="green"><td>BBB-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </br></td></tr>
<tr class="green"><td>BBB-application-04 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </br></td></tr>
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-01 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </br></td></tr>
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-02 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </br></td></tr>
<tr class="yellow"><td>CCC-application-03 <br> Qality_gate_failed_reason:xxxxxxx </br></td></tr>
```